# Actuators without spring-boot-starter-actuator dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Actuators are really helpful when it comes to having production-ready features.

We generally use `spring-boot-starter-actuator` dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Can we get these actuator endpoints by using other dependencies like Spring Boot Starter Web alone from `org.springframework.boot`?

Do actuators come along with all Spring Boot dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking to the currently newest version [2.7.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/2.7.2) at Maven Central you can learn it is [used by](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/usages) a lot of uploaded artifacts including the Spring ones. Sadly Maven doesn't implement a smart filter on the webpage.

Just a few to name from the first 10 pages:

- spring-cloud-context:3.1.3 (optional)
- spring-cloud-commons:3.1.3 (optional)
- spring-cloud-stream:3.2.4 (optional)
- spring-cloud-bus:3.1.2 (optional)
- spring-cloud-config-client:3.1.3 (optional)
- spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin:3.1.3 (optional)
- spring-cloud-config-server:3.1.3 (optional)
- [stream-applications-micrometer-common:3.2.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud.stream.app/stream-applications-micrometer-common/3.2.1) (**non-optional**)
- spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka:3.2.4 (optional)
- spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit:3.2.4 (optional)
- stream-applications-security-common:3.2.1 (optional)
- [spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul:2.2.10.RELEASE](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul/2.2.10.RELEASE) (**non-optional**)
- spring-cloud-openfeign-core/3.1.3 (optional)
- spring-cloud-sleuth-core:2.2.8.RELEASE (optional)
- spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client:3.1.3 (optional)

The `<optional>true</optional>` dependencies are prevented from being transitively included. While you can see the pattern that the Spring authors generally make this dependency optional regardless of the family (I haven't found a boot starter with the Actuator dependency, to be honest). You cannot rely on the actuator will or will not be included.